# How to add routes in a Play Framework 2.5.x?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.5

I am very new in Play framework. I am planning to add a very simple route. But it keeps saying that Action not found.

It works only for the index.

Action not found:

[image]

My Application.java:

```
public class Application extends Controller {

    public Result index() {
        return ok(index.render());
    }

    public Result home() {
        return ok(home.render());
    }  

}
```

The routes configuration file:

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~


# Landing page
GET        /                                 controllers.Application.index()


GET         /home                            controllers.Application.home()


# Map the JS resource paths
GET        /*file                            controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

Tried `activator clean compile`, but still it does not work.

Comment: have you tried clean-all?

Comment: @DenisBarucic Yes. I did.

Comment: Do you have any modules installed in your application ? Can it be that there are many routes files in the same project ? Check if it's really the file in conf/routes and not some other routes file.

Comment: @ALEX_AME It's the routes files. The index works but not the home.

Comment: @ALEX_AME I fixed it. Had to add a comment before the route. It's weird, very weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is how I fixed it.

```
# Landing page
GET        /                                 controllers.Application.index()

#After entering username and password
GET         /home                                   controllers.Application.home()
```

Added a comment before the route command. It's weird, very weird.

Comment: @ALEX_AME Some kind of bug, may be with Play framework. The documentation of Play Framework never mentions this. And the problem with the play documentation is that it is very hard to follow, what they want to say.

Comment: When I started with Play the templates helped me a lot, many of those examples are real world examples: http://www.lightbend.com/activator/templates

Comment: @ALEX_AME Cool. I will follow those.